# Video games and movies webservices

Tags: web-services, soap, where-clause, movies

I'm trying to find a webservice (prefer SOAP) that provides information on videogames and/or movies (need both). I've been trying this for a while and came up with nothing... Does anyone knows one of these?
(I'm trying to avoid HTML parsing from imdb, gamespot, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this: http://www.gamecompare.com/GameCompare.asmx?WSDL